# How do mods work?

Tags: c++

How exactly do people get mods to work, for example, in a game?
By mods I mean additions to the final executable.

If I were to make a game (Using a compiled language), could I allow for myself or others to make additions to it without having to create some kind of scripting language.

My idea: (would this work?)

- In the base program itself, create a stack or FIFO or even a linked list.
- Then outside the program, a loader would load the base and any mods, then pass the address of the mods to the base program.
- Finally, the base program does its thing, then switches execution to the mods(Perhaps with some kind of callback mechanism, like a [gasp!] goto). When they're done, code execution goes back to the base where it can do its own thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you will expose some of your application (game?) internal interfaces and objects to the mod writers. The mod writer will build a dll, that uses these objects and interfaces to do something useful. The application will then load mod dll dynamically and call the mod implementation where necessary.

Another way to think about it, is to imagine that your game is an operating system (Windows), and your mod is an application (Word). The OS provides some APIs to create, and manage windows, the application utilizes them where necessary.

So as a game dev your may create and distribute the following interface:

```
//mod.h
class Mod {
    //takes suggested damage as an arg and returns modified damage
    virtual int takeDamage(int damage);
};
```

And instruct the users to provide exported functions to instantiate and delete the mod objects.

Implement it:

```
//godmod.h
class GodMod : public Mod {
    int takeDamage(int damage) { return 0; } // god mode!!
}

__declspec(dllexport) Mod *create_mod() { return new GodMode(); }
__declspec(dllexport) void delete_mod(Mod *mod) { delete mod; }
```

Then you will have to load the dll (`LoadLibrary` API on Windows), export `create_mod` and `delete_mod` symbols with `GetProcAddress` API. Afterwards somewhere in the game you will instantiate the mod with `create_mod`, and use it where needed:

```
int damage = 100; //original damage
for (int i = 0; i < mods_count; i++) {
    damage = mods[i]->tageDamage(damage);
}
decrease_health(damage);
```

after all you will have to release the mod with `delete_mod` from the corresponding dll.

Comment: Looking forward for some crazy, moddable games ;)

Comment: but how can the game know if the dll it is importing has malicious code?

Answer (score 5):

Without implementing a scripting language it would work *similar* to how you described.  Windows has something called a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) and Linux has a similar concept called a Shared Object (SO).

In programs on either OS a program can dynamically (through looking for files in a certain directory or through a configuration file) load these files.  The files contain executable code just like a normal program, and the program that loaded them can then call functions inside them as long as the program knows the functions' names.

You can hard code functions' names, or put them in a configuration file, or make a single hard coded function name that returns names of other functions to load or pointers to the functions themselves.

This method is pretty common.  This is how mysql allows user defined functions and indexes, through loading shared libraries from a specific directory and calling a function supplied in a "LOAD PLUGIN" command.

Comment: After it's compiled, would you use the function's name or address? (from the config file)                                                Then you could specify a pre defined function to fall into from the main executable, like main().

Comment: @Will Young - In windows you aren't sure of the address until the DLL is loaded so you'd refer to the functions by name.  After the DLL is loaded you can call GetProcAddress to translate from the name to the address so you can call the function.

Comment: In linux there's a function called "dlsym" which is basically the same as GetProcAddress

Answer (score 5):

While this would work in theory, it is not the way it is usually done.

Mods most often are not implemented as native code. Mod friendly games usually use a data driven approach and provide some scripting language and configuration means, which are then used to implement the custom functionality of the mod.

The reasons for such approach are, besides others:

- it is an overkill to use C++ for implementing the high-level stuff mods are usually interested about, scripting languages are usually a lot easier to use and high performance of C++ is not needed there
- giving access to native code can cause serious security issues (both intentional and unintended, as it is hard to write native code which is not causing any memory leaks, memory access violations, and other issues)
- when using native callbacks, it is hard to define (and enforce) an interface between your game and mods

If you do not want to create your own scripting language, using some ready made (LUA is quite popular for games) is relatively easy.